# Cannot reply to outbound messages MobileConnect SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

We have an account where the Mobile Connect was set up long time ago and haven't been used for some time.
We recently realised that we can't reply to any SMS sent by the AU shortcode.
Is there something in the settings we should be checking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen after configuring custom "From Name" in the administrative section of Mobile Connect app, resulting in reply messages (codes/keywords) not being processed correctly by the system.

As an example, if you would like to reply to any messages with a "stop" keyword - you would have to send it to your short code as new message to make it work.

You can test your codes easily using "/sms/v1/queueMO" REST endpoint.